# Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

Tags: email

How can i fix this.

```
From: MAILER-DAEMON@adam.yocta.com (Mail Delivery System)
Date: 26 April 2016 at 5:50:23 PM GMT+4
To: contactus@immunity.ae
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

This is the mail system at host adam.yocta.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                  The mail system

<crystal@emirates.net.ae>: host dcmimail.emirates.net.ae[86.96.229.27] said:
   550 Invalid Recipient [609] (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; adam.yocta.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: F129338B56F
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; contactus@immunity.ae
Arrival-Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 19:20:20 +0530 (IST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; crystal@emirates.net.ae
Original-Recipient: rfc822;crystal@emirates.net.ae
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; dcmimail.emirates.net.ae
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Invalid Recipient [609]

From: Immunity Global Services <contactus@immunity.ae>
Date: 26 April 2016 at 5:50:19 PM GMT+4
To: crystal@emirates.net.ae
```

Comment: The email address you sent to does not exist.

Comment: Im experiencing the same issue and do not know how to fix it. Did you eventually find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear if your issue is from a client-side perspective or server side.

From a client-side perspective, this could simply mean you sent the email to a wrong email address, to the right domain but the address is wrong or not registered at all in their mail server. This could also mean that the email was returned because the recipients mailbox is full or due to other filtering reasons.

From a server-side perspective, you need to provide more information. But the fact that you were able to get a response from the mail server means that the request from the client-sender was received by the mail server. It was just not forwarded to the client-receiver and was returned to the client-sender by the mail server.